# Targeting Div for background color

Tags: css, html, web, background-color

I am trying to target the div so that it would allow me to add a background color to the red area I marked out below.

I have been trying with this #yui_3_10_1_1_1370470471782_587  but not sure if it is the correct one or not. If someone could take a look at it that would be great. Thank you

Here is the link to the page
http://jobspark.ca/job-listings/

[image]

Comment: Do you you know how to use developer tools like firebug? Using these you can easily drill down to find out which HTML elements relate to certain areas of the display.

Comment: Yeah I was using that and kept getting #yui_3_10_1_1_1370470471782_587

Comment: Is firebug way better then google chromes inspect option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your css

```
#page-header-51a2be41e4b0b3ec20471b4b{background-color:red}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you add an id to the element it will be very weird but you can target it with:

```
div #content div div div div{/*css here*/}
```